# Poor Error Handling: Unhandled Exception vulnerablity

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, security

In our application we are getting Poor Error Handling: Unhandled Exception 
I dont want to display the sqlException error codes with the error message.

```
Attack Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 14:21:13 GMT
Content-Length: 39032
...TRUNCATED...ation.
<br>
<br>
Exception Message: 20315 - **ORA-20315**: sa_check.save_customer: Unable to save order customer
information.ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "OA.SA_CHECK", line 968
ORA-06512: at line 1
<br>
<br>
Error: &nb...TRUNCATED...
```

Please help how i can handle it .

```
ORA-20315
ORA-06512
```

These types of Error number should not be displayed.

Thanks.

Comment: SQL handlers should catch these exceptions and send the error message accordingly!

Comment: but i want it should not send the actual  error codes like its displaying  currently

Comment: Exception Message: 20315 - *y*ORA-20315**: sa_check.save_customer: here ORA-20315 should not be displayed it's a vulnerability

Comment: Not sure an application-specific error code (in the -20000 range) is much of a vulnerability. Maybe you could show the code that's executing the `save_customer` call and generating the HTML; it's that which needs to replace the error with something even more generic, perhaps.

Comment: It should be use an error page with more user friendly message, and can log the exception in database or any storage to review the exception for debugging purpose